# Saxon - Out of memory when transforming

Tags: java, xml, memory, heap-memory, saxon

I need help trying to figure out what could be the cause of the memory exception when doing a transformation.

The code is this:

```
Transformer transformer = cachedXSLT.newTransformer();
String strXMLInput = this.toString();
StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(strXMLInput);
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlReader), result);
```

Where cachedXSLT is a Template and result a javax.xml.transform.Result

The log shows this:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:4138)
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3870)
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:119)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:454)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:355)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:425)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:138)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:187)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:501)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:643)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:780)
at net.sf.saxon.StandardErrorListener.error(StandardErrorListener.java:210)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.recoverableError(Controller.java:865)
at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.reportAmbiguity(Mode.java:593)
at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.getRule(Mode.java:257)
at net.sf.saxon.trans.RuleManager.getTemplateRule(RuleManager.java:160)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:329)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates$ApplyTemplatesPackage.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:527)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:317)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates$ApplyTemplatesPackage.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:527)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:317)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:210)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:174)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:556)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:93)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:296)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Choose.processLeavingTail(Choose.java:686)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:556)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:93)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:296)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:556)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:93)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:296)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:556)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:203)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:345)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.defaultAction(ApplyTemplates.java:378)
at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ApplyTemplates.applyTemplates(ApplyTemplates.java:333)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1807)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1621)
```

Analysing the heap its shown that the heap is occupied mostly by ByteArrayOutputStream

What could be generating the java heap space once the heap used showed in Introscope is around 60%.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the your JVM arguments?  Also how big is the dataset you are processing?

Comment: @bated Since it's an enterprise enviroment I don't even know the JVM arguments, all I know is that each JVM has 1.5GB alocated. The dataset will change dinamically at each request

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

You raised the same question here

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3488

and I quote my answer:

Saxon doesn't use any `ByteArrayOutputStream` instances internally; I think the only instances are the ones you are (presumably) supplying to hold the transformation result. How big is the result? Why are you putting the result in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Actually looking at the stack trace we have:

```
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flushBuffer(OutputStreamWriter.java:187)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:501)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:643)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:780)
at net.sf.saxon.StandardErrorListener.error(StandardErrorListener.java:210)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.recoverableError(Controller.java:865)
at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.reportAmbiguity(Mode.java:593)
```

so the ByteArrayOutputStream here appears to be the destination for warning messages output by the `StandardErrorListener`. Have you redirected this output perhaps?

You haven't said which Saxon version you are using: it looks like an old one, judging by the line numbers.

It might be a good idea to get rid of the ambiguities in your template rules to avoid the warning messages: put a priority attribute on template rules where several rules can match the same node.